# Get the first element in web with individual Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am running a little Python Selenium script and I want to access attributes from the first element on this site: https://www.mydealz.de/gruppe/spielzeug. Every few minutes the first element is different and has therefore a different Xpath identifier.
What are the possibilites to access all the time this first element, which has different id's/Xpaths? The first result I meant.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by first element ???you should have mentioned the element you are after??Where is your code trial???

Comment: please include your current script.

Comment: The first result I meant

Answer (score 0):

I've keep an eye open on the website for the last 15 minutes, but for me the page has not changed.

Nevertheless, I tried to scrape the data with BS4 (which you could populate with Selenium's current browser session), where it should always return the first element first.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.mydealz.de/gruppe/spielzeug')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")
price_info = soup.select(".cept-tp")

for element in price_info:
    for child in element:
        print(child)
```

Of course this is just for the price, but you can apply the same logic for the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

To print the first *title* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.threadGrid div.threadGrid-title.js-contextual-message-placeholder>strong.thread-title>a"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='threadGrid']//div[@class='threadGrid-title js-contextual-message-placeholder']/strong[@class='thread-title']/a"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output of two back to back execution:
- `[Mediamarkt @Ebay.de] diverse Gravitrax Erweiterungen günstig!`
- `[Mediamarkt @Ebay.de] diverse Gravitrax Erweiterungen günstig!`

> As per the documentation:
>
> - [`get_attribute(name)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)
>     method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
> - [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text)
>     attribute returns `The text of the element.`